# Vue.js Validator: TypeError when calling $validatorReset

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I call `this.$validatorReset` I get an Uncaught TypeError informing me that "`this.$validatorReset is not a function`"

**Update**
I switched to `vue-validator v2.0.0-alpha.17` as suggested. That introduced another layer of errors. Namely a new `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and a warning from Vue that it `Failed to resolve directive: validate'

It's happening in the app I'm building but reproducible in the following JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/8v5djgc0/2/

Am I misunderstanding the usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pulling in `vue-validator v2.0.0-alpha.10`, whereas the `$validatorReset`function was added in `vue-validator v2.0.0-alpha.17`.  Try pulling in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-validator/2.0.0-alpha.17/vue-validator.js

FYI though, with the alpha version changing so rapidly you may end up with other changes you need to make.

Edit: now you also need `Vue v1.0.16` - updated https://jsfiddle.net/hy5759n7/1/

Comment: Fair. Updating to `vue-validator v2.0.0-alpha.17` comes with its own issues. Namely, another `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and a warning from Vue that it `Failed to resolve directive: validate'… 

I updated the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/8v5djgc0/2/

Comment: That did it, thank you! Here's hoping updating Vue in the app doesn't break all the things now.
Updated the Fiddle, too: https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/8v5djgc0/4/

Comment: @ItoPizarro You don't have to worry about that part as much.  With semantic versioning, going from 1.0.12 to 1.0.16 shouldn't cause any breaking changes.  Vue would change to 1.1.0 if something was that big, it's just the validator alpha version you have to keep an eye on :)